# Paired samples t test in Python

Tags: t-test, python, paired-data, statsmodels

I'm trying to conduct a paired samples t-test in Python (statsmodels package), but I don't see a function for it in their documentation. The closest I can find is [ttost_paired](http://www.statsmodels.org/0.9.0/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttost_paired.html#statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttost_paired), but I don't think its correct as their null hypothesis is that the mean difference is > or < some boundary value, whereas for my desired test the null is `x1 - x2 = 0`

A few questions:

1. Is there a way to do a paired samples t-test in statsmodels that I'm missing?
2. Is there a way to use `ttost_paired` to do what I want?
3. They do also have an [independent samples ttest](http://www.statsmodels.org/0.9.0/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttest_ind.html#statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttest_ind). What could go wrong if I use an independent ttest on paired data?

I know I can do a paired t-test using scipy but I'm wondering specifically about statsmodels

Comment: A paired sample t-test is just a one sample t-test on the difference of the two samples, i.e. t_test(x1 - x2, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function `ttost` is not a t-test and therefore is not suitable for your purposes. 
The TTOST is a test of non-equivalence. It employes two one-sided t-tests in order to verify if both samples are equivalent or not. Please, have a look at the function documentation.

There exists the [ttest_mean function](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.ttest_mean.html#statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.ttest_mean) on the `statsmodels` package. However, it does not indicate if the test is conducted with paired samples or not. Thus, I recommend you to use the scipy.stats t-test.

And about your last question:

> They do also have an independent samples ttest. What could go wrong if I use an independent ttest on paired data?

The paired t-test reduces intersubject variability. Thus, it is theoretically more powerful than the unpaired t-test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ttest_rel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html) function in scipy.stats:

> Calculate the t-test on TWO RELATED samples of scores, a and b. This
>   is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 related or repeated
>   samples have identical average (expected) values.

Answer (score 1):

Standard paired t-test for two samples y1 and y2 is just the one sample t-test applied on the difference `d = y1 - y2`.
The same applies when using a normal distribution in a z-test.

(That and the availability of paired t-test in scipy.stats are the reasons why statsmodels currently does not implement a separate paired t-test.)